# yii - Trying to get non property object

Tags: php, join, yii

```
       $critPost = "SELECT * FROM `post` `t` join `ss_individual` `p` ON `t`.`user_id` = `p`.`id` WHERE `t`.`del`=0 and `t`.`hide`=0 and `t`.`user_id`='".Yii::app()->user->id."' ORDER BY `t`.`posted_on` desc";
       $modelPost = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($critPost)->queryAll();
       print_r($modelPost); /* it works fine */
       foreach($modelPost as $mp)
       {
           echo $mp->imgname; /* trying to get non property object */
       }
```

Am joining two tables 'post' and 'ss_individual' and executing using Yii::app()->db->createCommand($critPost)->queryAll(). While displaying using print_r($modelPost). It works fine, but it showing error while using foreach().

Answer (score 1):

When you use `createCommand(...)->queryAll()` you get not an array of objects but an array arrays. Try get this value as follows:

```
foreach($modelPost as $mp)
{
    echo $mp['imgname']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. it will be object

```
 echo $mp->imgname;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Actually i tried this ` echo $mp->imgname; `. But it doesn't work out.

Comment: pls paste the print_r($modelPost) output